# Custom Actionbar in fragment android

Tags: android, methods, android-actionbar, fragment, call

I create simple project using actionbar ,i've one class and one fragment class, i define custome actionbar in class, and my problem, how to call method actionbar in fragment class from class,
this code like below :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_holder);
    fragmentArray = new ConferenceFragment[8];
    // Load main fragment
    fragment = new HomeFragment();
    fragmentArray[0] = fragment;
    currentFragmentIndex = 0;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.holder, fragment).commit();
//        initMenuBar();
}

public void initMenuBar(){
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.menu_bar);

    ImageButton buttonSideMenu = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt_menu);
    buttonSideMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        toggle();
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    actionBar.show();
}
```

// fragment class

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

    View v;
    MainActivity mainactivity;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mainActivity.initMenuBar(); // ERROR IN THIS LINE
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);

        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html) is traditionally the part of Activity and is available to activity only. You can get Activity instance by calling [getActivity()](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity()) from fragment and cast it to your activity then call public method to do whatever you want.

But the better option is to use [ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) explained here [support library v7](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Comment: i don't understand with your mind , my problem like above , how to call method in activity class from fragment ?

Comment: i.e.   YourActivity activity =  (YourActivity)getActivity(); then activity.initMenuBar();

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your MainActivity's context reference in your fragment to access activity's method.

Try this.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

    View v;
    Context mContext;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
        mContext = getActivity();
        ((MainActivity) mContext).initMenuBar();
        return v;
    }

}
```